# React json object value doesn't show up

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

i'm creating a project with MongoDB, Next.js and React, but i get an error: 
I want to display a json object, but nothing appear. 
Here my code:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { connectToDatabase } from '../lib/mongodb'
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Home({ isConnected }) {

  const [showQueue, setQueue] = useState('');

  function getQueue() {
  
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/queue')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.queue[0])
        setQueue(response.queue)
    })

  }

  getQueue()

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1 className="title">
        {showQueue}
        </h1>

        {isConnected ? (
          <h2 className="subtitle">You are connected to MongoDB</h2>
        ) : (
          <h2 className="subtitle">
          </h2>
        )}

      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { client } = await connectToDatabase()

  const isConnected = await client.isConnected()

  return {
    props: { isConnected },
  }
}
```

File who send the object:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../lib/mongodb";
export default async (req, res) => {

  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  const queue = await db.collection("queue").findOne({name: "queue"})

  res.send({queue: queue.queue});


};
```

The variable doesn't show up and i get this error:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, author}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

PS: I'm new to React
How i can fix that? 
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your `showQueue` is an object with the properties name and author. you need to change your code to {showQueue.author}

Comment: @Shyam yes i tried, the error doesn't show up anymore, but doesn't show up the text